# Athena SQL date

Tags: sql, string, datetime, presto, amazon-athena

I queried the Athena database to get starttime and endtime. And I'm trying find the duration between start time and end time, and. used date diff function to get that information. But I guess the datatype and format of date in not enabling to use date diff.

Here is the query:
SELECT,
json_extract_scalar(eventdata, 'starttime') AS starttime,
json_extract_scalar(eventdata, 'endtime')  AS endtime
FROM table1

Here is the sample data:

[image]

How can I find the duration? Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`from_iso8601_timestamp()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html?highlight=from_iso8601_timestamp#from_iso8601_timestamp) to turn these formated strings to timestamps. Then you can use [`date_diff()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html?highlight=date_diff#date_diff):

```
select 
    json_extract_scalar(eventdata, 'starttime') as starttime, 
    json_extract_scalar(eventdata, 'endtime') as endtime,
    date_diff(
        'second',   -- or another unit you like
        from_iso8601_timestamp(json_extract_scalar(eventdata, 'endtime')),
        from_iso8601_timestamp(json_extract_scalar(eventdata, 'starttime'))
    ) diff_seconds
from table1
```